# How to pass different data object to customize list adapter in android

Tags: android

I have 3 different do classes (It contain data it will return the list). I have the conditon if user selects TableName, I have to Pass TableDo in Adapter generate TableDo value in listview. If user selects Chair, I have to Pass ChairDo to adapter to generate chairdo value in list view.
Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor for adapter simply add a flag so that it tells you what list to laod and other  functionalities to include.

eg

```
 Adapter(Context context,ArrayList myList,int option){
     switch(option){
         case TABLE:
         //GET array list for table
         case CHAIR:
         //GET array list for chair
     }
}
```

similarly you can do the same at other places in this adapter